# EFCore, CodeFirst, Many To Many relation - do I need a key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My model:

```cs
public class List : Blame {
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

}

public class ListBinding : Blame {

    public int EntryId { get; set; }
    public int ListId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntryId")]
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ListId")]
    public List List { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    // ... all other configuration ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<ListBinding>().HasNoKey();
}
```

Is it right and efficient?

Do I get it right?

There is a tiny table binding `List` items with `Entry` items by their keys. As the base class could suggest, the table also contains some metadata about who and when made the changes to it. So - why would I need a primary key for such table? I think it's perfectly redundant.

I think primary keys are also redundant for tiny tables containing 1 column, right?

OK, my smallest table contains also 4 columns with metadata, 2 date/time columns, and 2 small string columns. User identifiers are foreign keys in my `Users` table, so I've read the framework creates indices for these columns by default.

So - there are 2 date columns and one data column without an index. Should it have a primary key or not?

Oh, here's the tiny table:

```cs
public class Tag : Blame {
        
    public int EntryId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntryId")]
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }

}
```

Leaving my configuration like this:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    // ... all other configuration ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<ListBinding>().HasNoKey();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasNoKey();
}
```

...And if you really want to know what are the "metadata" I'm talking about, here:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyApp.Data {

    public abstract class Blame {

        [Required]
        public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime TimeModified { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(50)]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        #region Foreign keys

        [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
        public User CreatorUser { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")]
        public User ModifierUser { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Helpers

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the CreatedBy, TimeCreated, ModifiedBy, TimeModified properties of models inheriting from <see cref="Blame"/> abstract class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userId">User identifier.</param>
        /// <param name="keepCreated">Set true to keep existing CreatedBy and TimeCreated values.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Model type.</typeparam>
        public void BlameUser(string userId, bool keepCreated = false) {
            if (!keepCreated) {
                CreatedBy = userId;
                TimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
            }
            ModifiedBy = userId;
            TimeModified = DateTime.Now;
        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```

I have my main table `Entries`. It is fairly big, has primary keys, indices and foreign keys. Later in development the client ordered a features to mark rows with tags, and create a custom, disposable lists of such rows.

I could add columns to my `Entry` model, sure, but there will be very small amount of marked rows, or rows added to lists compared with the `Entry` model row count. So to avoid creating hundreds of thousands empty cells I just created 3 related models, `Tag`, `List`, and `ListBinding`.

BTW, to realize the relation between row counts: `Entry` model table will contain all items from several business years. Lists and tags will contain items from maximum a business week.

So - is the structure optimal, or am I missing something?

Comment: So basically what you are asking is, when designing a database, why/when you need a primary key on a table. This has nothing to do with Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core.

Comment: For EF Core, you can read [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) documentation. There you'll see what are their capabilities, and more importantly - their limitations. Since they have no unique key, EFC cannot track them, thus does not support CUD operations. That's why it's always good to have primary/unique key. It doesn't need to be separate - m2m tables standartly use composite PK consisting of FK columns.

Comment: @atiyar: No. I don't. I do not ask why I need primary keys on tables. I'm asking about a specific case, considering EF does things implicitly.

Comment: @IvanStoev Now I'm super confused. Then why the EF created the tables for them in my database? It's weird, but it looks like I have to use keys, even if they are not necessary for performance reasons.